How do you change the title on the tab when using Storybook
For more clarification the title I'm referring to is next on the tab next to the Favicon on a browser, currently mine is like this: Example / Button - Docs ⋅ Storybook, and I can't seem to get rid of the ⋅ Storybook part or edit it to how I want.
addons.setConfig({
  theme: create({
    brandTitle: "New Title",
    base: "light",
    brandImage: logo,
  })
});

and adding this to main.ts config
managerHead: (head) => 
    `${head}
      <script>
    document.title = 'New Title';
  </script>
      `
  ,

But nothing seems to change it. Does anyone know how I can change this?
